# Is there a way to algorithmically check continuity?

Tags: general-topology

If I am given a function between two non finite topological spaces, is there an algorithmic way to check it's continuity in finite steps? If no, how would I show the non existence of such an algorithim?

Comment: I would say no, and just a thought, a way to prove it could maybe be defining a correspondence with the halting problem in some sense.

Comment: If the spaces are infinite, how is the function given?

Comment: I would imagine there'd be some sort of evaluation rule givne. Similar to how we write stuff like f(x) = some exp in x , for functions R-> R @lhf

Comment: You need to be more precise: it is not obvious how to model computable functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, one issue being that over a finite (or countable) alphabet, finite strings can only represent countably many elements of $\mathbb{R}$. You also have not specified how the topology is encoded.

Comment: On the other hand, there certainly are topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ for which there are algorithms (once you've chosen some encoding) to determine whether a function $X \to Y$ is continuous. For instance, if $X$ is discrete the algorithm is: "Yes".